# Android delete item from Listview

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I have a adapter with this code:

```
        public class LoadOrders_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private JSONArray data;
private Context context;

public LoadOrders_adapter(JSONArray data, Context context) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

        return data.length();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    try {
        return data.get(position);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_orderlist, parent, false);

    ImageView product_images=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_images);
    TextView Total_quantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Total_quantity);
    TextView order_status=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
    TextView order_date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.order_date);
    TextView order_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
    TextView product_Name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_Name);

    try {
        JSONObject temp = data.getJSONObject(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(WebConnection.getInstance().resource_url(temp.getString("imgUrl"))).into(product_images);
        Total_quantity.setText(temp.getString("Quantity"));
        order_date.setText(temp.getString("Date_Sub"));
        order_id.setText("#"+temp.getString("Order_ID"));
        order_status.setText(temp.getString("Status"));
        product_Name.setText(temp.getString("Name"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return row;

}
```

}

And a class called:

```
    public class LoadOrders extends ActionBarActivity implements Top_fragment.Top_fragmentListener {

private JSONArray data = null;
private JSONArray OrderDetails2 = null;
private ListView Normal_Orders_list;
private String previous_activity = "info.sliit.mystyle.Home";
private String title_name = "Your Normal Orders";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_promotional_wear);
    Normal_Orders_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Normal_Orders_list);
    new BackgroundProcess().execute();
}

class BackgroundProcess extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoadOrders.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        data = WebConnection.getInstance().get_request("Loading_order_rest/orderloading/user_id/12","json");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        BaseAdapter baseAdapter1 = new LoadOrders_adapter(data,LoadOrders.this);
        Normal_Orders_list.setAdapter(baseAdapter1);
        //Normal_Orders_list.setOnItemClickListener();

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_customized_orders,menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public String get_previous_activity() {
    return previous_activity;
}

@Override
public String getTitle_name() {
    return title_name;
}
```

}

I have an activity called Activity_loading_orders which has a list view called Normal_Orders_list and i have another layout called loading_orderlist which has has a RelativeLayout with some Textviews and a button. As you can see in the code the layout loading_orderlist is loaded as an list item into the Normal_Orders_list activity. What i want to do is to remove list items when the button is clicked see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yia.jpg

Comment: It's not very clear what is going on here.  It sounds like all of these forms are child controls in a panel on the main form, which makes the MDI information not relevant.  If this *is* an MDI issue, then you might have to access the form's MDIParent property.  `panel1.Controls.Clear()` does not dispose of anything, btw, so you are potentially leaking memory there.

Comment: exactly they are child forms of the main form. Im a bit new to this please help me with this.

Comment: But your code is making them TopLevel = False, BorderStyle.None and child *controls* of a local panel.  Get rid of those lines then and make it `act.MDIParent = this;`  (Assuming this code is coming from the main form.

Comment: the mian form is called form1 and there is a panel in that form into which i load the Actionview form using the above code in a button click event.What i need is to again load a new form called logfiles to the same panel using a button placed in the actionview form.

Comment: That has nothing to do with MDI.

Comment: ok but i have set the main form which is Form1 as mdi parent from its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing parent of created objects after creation?  You create two objects in panel1. One of them is actionview form, other is logview form. So you should  change parent of created items to panel1

```
actionview.Parent = panel1;
actionview.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

logfiles.Parent = panel1;
logfiles.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Maybe it can help.

Comment: what i need is to load Actionview form into panel1 from a button in logfiles form.

Comment: Replace order of codes. First change parent of logfiles with dockstyle.top then after actionview with dockstyle.fill

Comment: please help me a edited the question now its more clear.